# Saving geotiff map in hector_slam

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone

I'm currently working on a project that involves using hector slam with a lidar to map its surroundings. At the moment I have hector slam building maps really well so now I'm trying to save these maps every few seconds during the mapping process as geotiff files.

I'm running ROS Kinetic on a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Mate. I have created a directory called "hector_geotiff/maps" in my home directory in which to save these images. This directory is being referenced in the launch files below. While the mapping process is running I am using the command

```
 rostopic pub syscommand std_msgs/String "savegeotiff"
```

Doing this yields no error messages and gives the output "publishing and latching message. Press ctrl-C to terminate" This gives me the impression that its working and trying to save the files however there are no images appearing in the given directory.

I have attached my launch files for tutorial.launch, mapping_default.launch & geotiff_mapper.launch below as well as the output for rostopic list and rosnode list.

Tutorial.launch

```
<launch>

  <arg name="geotiff_map_file_path" default="~hector_geotiff/maps"/>

  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="false"/>

  <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz"
    args="-d $(find hector_slam_launch)/rviz_cfg/mapping_demo.rviz"/>

  <include file="$(find hector_mapping)/launch/mapping_default.launch"/>

  <include file="$(find hector_geotiff)/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch">
    <arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" value="scanmatcher_frame"/>
    <arg name="map_file_path" value="$(arg geotiff_map_file_path)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

Geotiff_mapper.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="trajectory_source_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="trajectory_update_rate" default="4"/>
  <arg name="trajectory_publish_rate" default="0.25"/>
  <arg name="map_file_path" default="~hector_geotiff/maps"/>
  <arg name="map_file_base_name" default="hector_slam_map"/>

  <node pkg="hector_trajectory_server" type="hector_trajectory_server" name="hector_trajectory_server" output="screen">
    <param name="target_frame_name" type="string" value="/map" />
    <param name="source_frame_name" type="string" value="$(arg trajectory_source_frame_name)" />
    <param name="trajectory_update_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_update_rate)" />
    <param name="trajectory_publish_rate" type="double" value="$(arg trajectory_publish_rate)" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="hector_geotiff" type="geotiff_node" name="hector_geotiff_node" output="screen" launch-prefix="nice -n 15">
    <remap from="map" to="/dynamic_map" />
    <param name="map_file_path" type="string" value="$(arg map_file_path)" />
    <param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="$(arg map_file_path)" />
    <param name="geotiff_save_period" type="double" value="2" />
    <param name="draw_background_checkerboard" type="bool" value="true" />
    <param name="draw_free_space_grid" type="bool" value="true" />
    <param name="plugins" type="string" value="hector_geotiff_plugins/TrajectoryMapWriter" />
  </node>

</launch>
```

Mapping_default.launch

```
<launch>
  <arg name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" default="scanmatcher_frame"/>
  <arg name="base_frame" default="base_link"/>
  <arg name="odom_frame" default="base_link"/>
  <arg name="pub_map_odom_transform" default="true"/>
  <arg name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" default="5"/>
  <arg name="scan_topic" default="scan"/>
  <arg name="map_size" default="2048"/>
  
  <node pkg="hector_mapping" type="hector_mapping" name="hector_mapping" output="screen">
    
    <!-- Frame names -->
    <param name="map_frame" value="map" />
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg base_frame)" />
    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg odom_frame)" />
    
    <!-- Tf use -->
    <param name="use_tf_scan_transformation" value="true"/>
    <param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="false"/>
    <param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="$(arg pub_map_odom_transform)"/>
    
    <!-- Map size / start point -->
    <param name="map_resolution" value="0.050"/>
    <param name="map_size" value="$(arg map_size)"/>
    <param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
    <param name="map_multi_res_levels" value="2" />
    
    <!-- Map update parameters -->
    <param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.9" />    
    <param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.4"/>
    <param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
    <param name="laser_z_min_value" value = "-1.0" />
    <param name="laser_z_max_value" value = "1.0" />
    
    <!-- Advertising config --> 
    <param name="advertise_map_service" value="true"/>
    
    <param name="scan_subscriber_queue_size" value="$(arg scan_subscriber_queue_size)"/>
    <param name="scan_topic" value="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    
    <!-- Debug parameters -->
    <!--
      <param name="output_timing" value="false"/>
      <param name="pub_drawings" value="true"/>
      <param name="pub_debug_output" value="true"/>
    -->
    <param name="tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name" value="$(arg tf_map_scanmatch_transform_frame_name)" />
  </node>
    
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_to_laser_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link laser 100" />

</launch>



rosnode list
/base_to_laser_broadcaster
/hector_geotiff_node
/hector_mapping
/hector_trajectory_server
/rosout
/rplidarNode
/rviz

 rostopic list
    /clicked_point
    /initialpose
    /map
    /map_metadata
    /map_updates
    /move_base_simple/goal
    /poseupdate
    /rosout
    /rosout_agg
    /scan
    /slam_cloud
    /slam_out_pose
    /syscommand
    /tf
    /tf_static
    /trajectory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301186/saving-geotiff-map-in-hector_slam/) by [TintinQuarantino](https://answers.ros.org/users/36866/tintinquarantino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Had a win today! To figure out my issue I downloaded the original hector slam package and ran it with a bag file to ensure that I was able to save geotiffs that way. I then compared the launch files for any discrepancies between the two. One other point is that I made a maps file in the hector_geotiff file within the actual catkin filepath (should have done that in the first place).

I think in the end my problem was that in my geotiff_mapper.launch file somehow I had the following line

```
<param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="$(arg map_file_path)" />
```

This meant that the geotiff node was trying to use the filepath as the filename for example ~/xxx/xxx/hector_geotiff/maps/xxx/xxx/hector_geotiff/maps

It worked exactly as expected after I changed the map_file_base_name parameter to the following

```
<param name="map_file_base_name" type="string" value="$(arg map_file_base_name)" />
```

Hope this helps anyone that may have made a similar silly mistake.

---

Originally posted by [TintinQuarantino](https://answers.ros.org/users/36866/tintinquarantino/) with karma: 26 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-23**:
+1 for reporting back. Much appreciated.